# The z-index of a border image around my site is higher than a button, but I want the button's link to still be clickable despite having lower z-index

Tags: css, image, hyperlink, border, z-index

On the **mobile site** of https://lostboysfoundgirls.com/studio/ there is an image acting as a border around the site and the buttons on the lower z-index become unclickable under this top border image. Obviously I want the buttons to scroll under the border image visually, but in doing this with z-index (buttons lower, border higher) the link click isn't initiated due to the z-index positioning.

Another example of a similar issue is on http://lowlifeclothing.co/ with multiple images displayed on the home page. They are all clickable images with links attached. All of the images on the home page are on the same z-index, but some of the images overlap each other and make other images unclickable.

How do I make all the links in my images work with this overlap occurring? Can I make it so clickable links always take priority despite image overlap or a border image with a higher z-index or two images with links overlapping?

Answer (score 0):

you can add the following css to the buttons

```
.elementor-button-link {
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px !important;
    z-index: 999;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    text-align: center;
}
```

The only disadvantage of this solution is that you have to set a fixed width for the buttons otherwise it will be 100% to its parent.